# Using reducers in GEE to calculate mean monthly precipitation from hourly data

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, code-review

Using the Copernicus ERA5-Land Hourly dataset as an ImageCollection, I want to calculate average monthly precipitation data for 344 climate divisions in the US as a FeatureCollection. The climate division files were downloaded from NOAA's website. I've already ran code to retrieve each hourly value for temperature and dewpoint temperature  [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/31da2f39de920022984d323ac35675fa), and these results are accurate.

Now, I want to get the monthly means of precipitation data for all 344 climate divisions in the US from 1970-2022 in single year sections. I'm trying to produce a CSV with a monthly mean for total_precipitation and total_precipitation_hourly for each month in each climate division. I have been using reducers to get the mean of the hourly data. Currently, I'm running this [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8ccac666fe1098e436d55274dd4c83ec?noload=1), but it's not producing accurate results. When running only one year, it returned about 700 rows of precipitation data for the first month of a single climate division, when I want just 1 row for each month and 12 rows for a year. I believe the code is making a new row for every single image in the ImageCollection, instead of producing the mean of all the images for a month. I think the issue is in how I'm using reducers and the acquisitionTime variable in this section of the code:

```
var calculateMeanValues = function(feature, dataset, year) {
  var meanValues = dataset.map(function(image) {
    var Total_Precipitation = image.select('total_precipitation');
    var Total_Precipitation_Hourly = image.select('total_precipitation_hourly');

    var meanValueInFeature = Total_Precipitation.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: feature.geometry(),
      scale: 1000, // Adjust as needed
      bestEffort: true
    }).get('total_precipitation');
    
     var meanValuesInFeature = Total_Precipitation_Hourly.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: feature.geometry(),
      scale: 1000, // Adjust as needed
      bestEffort: true
    }).get('total_precipitation_hourly');

    // Get date and time properties from the image
    var acquisitionTime = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'));
    var month = acquisitionTime.get('month');
    
    return ee.Feature(null, {
      'Total_Precipitation': meanValueInFeature,
      'Total_Precipitation_Hourly': meanValuesInFeature,
      'CLIMDIV': feature.get('CLIMDIV'),
      'Year': year,
      'Month': month
      
    });
  });
  return meanValues;
};
```

How can I reduce the hourly data to a monthly mean for each climate division?